# How can I remove elements and append new elements after the nth <li> in a <ul> list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul style="margin-bottom: 0;" id="stats-results" class="message">
   <li>DS1 Records: <span id="ds1Count"></span></li>
   <li>DEV Records: <span id="devCount"></span></li>
   <li>Added: <span id="Added"></span></li>
   <li>Rejected: <span id="Rejected"></span></li>
   <li>Updated: <span id="Updated"></span></li>
   <li>xxx</li>
</ul>
```

How can I remove any `<li>` elements that are present after the 5th `<li>`?

Also I have this code:

```
$.each(data.Events, function (i, item) {
    $("#stats-list").append('<li>' + item.Description + ' : ' + item.Elapsed + ' ms</li>');
});
```

Is there a way I could change this so that it appends after the 5th `<li>`

Answer (score 6):

Part 1

```
$('#stats-results li:gt(4)').remove();
```

Part 2

To add each element in your list after the 5th element successively, essentially reversing the order of the elements that you add, you can do this:

```
$.each(data.Events, function (i, item) {
    $("#stats-list li:eq(4)").after('<li>' + item.Description + ' : ' + item.Elapsed + ' ms</li>');
});
```

Or, to retain the order of the elements you're adding, but start them at the 5th index:

```
$.each(data.Events, function (i, item) {
    $("#stats-list li:eq("+(4+i)+")").after('<li>' + item.Description + ' : ' + item.Elapsed + ' ms</li>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks - How about a way to append after the 5th li?

Comment: @samantha Added :). This adds each one after the 5th li, meaning the order is essentially reversed...is that what you want? Meh...added the other method anyway, just in case :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nextAll`:

```
$('#stats-results li:eq(4)').nextAll().remove();
```

And `after` method:

```
var html = '';
$.each(data.Events, function (i, item) {
    html += '<li>' + item.Description + ' : ' + item.Elapsed + ' ms</li>';
});
$("#stats-list li:eq(4)").after(html)
```